# Need to know how to clone using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was just wondering how close i am getting to cloning this div i dont really have alot of idea on what i am doing at this stage help is needed.

or should i use jquery

```
<div id="question20">20. Details of Children
    <br>Family Name
    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
    <br>Given Names
    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
    <br>Sex
    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
    <br>Date of Birth
    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
    <br>Country of Birth
    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
    <br>
    <script>
        function cloning() {
            var container = document.getElementById("mydiv");
            var clone = document.getElementById("question20_0").cloneNode(true);
            clone.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + document.getElementById("mydiv").getElementsByTagName("question20").length);
            container.appendChild(clone);
    </script>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Press This" onclick="cloning()">
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your code to do what I think you want to do, you can find it demonstrated here with comments on what you were doing wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/v876k/1/

Here's the functional code with the comments stripped out:

```
<script>
function cloning() {
    var container = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    var clone = document.getElementById("question20").cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + container.childNodes.length);
    container.appendChild(clone);
}
</script>

<div id="question20">20. Details of Children
    <br>Family Name
    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
    <br>Given Names
    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
    <br>Sex
    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
    <br>Date of Birth
    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
    <br>Country of Birth
    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
    <br>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Press This" onclick="cloning()">

<div id="mydiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go through the below code.

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <div id="question20">
        20. Details of Children<br>
        Family Name<input type="text" name="children" class="textbox"><br>
        Given Names<input type="text" name="children" class="textbox"><br>
        Sex<input type="text" name="children" class="textbox"><br>
        Date of Birth<input type="text" name="children" class="textbox"><br>
        Country of Birth<input type="text" name="children" class="textbox"><br>

    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Press This" onclick="cloning()">
<script>
function cloning() {
    var container = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    var clone = document.getElementById("question20").cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('id','div_'+document.getElementById("mydiv").getElementsByTagName("div").length);
    container.appendChild (clone);
}
</script>
```

These were the mistakes,

- You missed `}` for the function
- You referred to `question20_0` instead of `question20`

Comment: I like this answer, but you missed the error in setting the ID of the cloned element. See my answer for how I remedied that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `clone()` in jquery.

HTML :

```
<input type="button" value="Press This" class="clone">
```

Script:

```
$(".clone").click(function(){
    $("#question20").clone().insertAfter("div.mydiv:last");
});
```

Read http://api.jquery.com/clone/ for more details.

Cheers
Roy

Answer (score 0):

you should use the .cloneNode() function in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/clone/